# Is there an option to count pairs of words in a list of concatenated words in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a list of transactions with the product that were purchased - I'm trying to see what items are frequently bought together. A transaction can have 1 item purchased or multiple items.

```
transaction_id | Product Name
 1              | A
 1              | B
 1              | C
 2              | A
 3              | A
 3              | B
```

I would like to get:

```
AB: 2
AC: 1
BC: 1
```

Some transactions can have even 20 items.

I managed to get rid of the transactions that only have 1 product purchased, I tried grouping by transaction_id and concatenating the product name, but that still won't let me count pairs.

Comment: Your title suggests wou want to count words but the example data uses single chars it is very contradictory

Comment: @RaymondNijland I simply assumed it's easier to work on 'A' and 'B' than on 'Saxon 600D Combo Medium'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t1.product, t2.product, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id and
        t1.product < t2.product
group by t1.product, t2.product;
```

Note:  This assumes that the rows are not duplicated.

Comment: To prevent duplicate combinations like AB and BA shouldn' t the condition be: `t1.product < t2.product`?

Comment: @forpas . . . Yes.  The OP doesn't explicitly say to not include those.  But the results clearly do not have duplicates.

Comment: @forpas thank you so much! I literally spent past 30 min trying to figure out how to get rid of duplicates.
SQL keeps surprising me with these simple solutions. 
Thanks again and thank you GordonLinoff

Comment: @JanKierzyk it's Gordon's answer, not mine.

Comment: @forpas without your comment I wouldn't notice the t1.product<t2.product so thank you both